# How to render an array of complex objects with pdf make?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, pdfmake

I am trying to process an array of complex objects into a readable format with [pdfMake](http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/). Here's the array:

```js
var areaImpact = [
{  
   "riskID":"f0bf6fa1-0a6b-e6e3-9ec08bd67751",
   "description":"Matt's printing testMatt's printing testMatt's printing test",
   "type":"Safety",
   "consequences":{  
      "items":[  
         "Matt's printing test",
         "Matt's printing again"
      ]
   },
   "safeguards":{  
      "items":[  
         "Matt's printing test",
         "Matt's printing test agin!!!"
      ]
   },
   "actions":{  
      "items":[  
         "Matt's awesome printing test"
      ]
   }
},
{  
   "riskID":"ffd23fa1-0a6b-e6e3-9ec08bd67751",
   "description":"Here's another test",
   "type":"Safety",
   "consequences":{  
      "items":[  
         "Matt's printing test",
         "Matt's printing again"
      ]
   },
   "safeguards":{  
      "items":[  
         "Matt's printing test",
         "Matt's printing test agin!!!"
      ]
   },
   "actions":{  
      "items":[  
         "Matt's awesome printing test"
      ]
   }
}
]
```

I would like the the pdf to look like this:
[Risk List Concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iYtB.png).
 I've having trouble thinking this through. How would I do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

After a good night's rest, I was able to figure this one out. Probably not the only way to do this, nor the best way, but here's what I did:

```js
function formatRiskList(riskList){
  var printableRisks = [];

  riskList.forEach(function(risk){

   printableRisks.push({text:'Description', style:'subheader'});
   printableRisks.push({text:risk.description});
   printableRisks.push({text:'Consequences', style:'subheader'});
   printableRisks.push({ul: risk.consequences.items});
   printableRisks.push({text:'Safegaurds', style:'subheader'});
   printableRisks.push({ul: risk.safeguards.items});   
   printableRisks.push({text:'Actions', style:'subheader'});
   printableRisks.push({ul: risk.actions.items});

  });
      
   return printableRisks;   

 }
  
  //And then, in the docdefinition, I did this:
  var dd = {content: [formatRiskList(areaImpact.riskList.items)]};
```

Pretty straightforward. I'm not sure why I was having issues with this last night. I think it had something to do with how I was trying to nest objects VS arrays. Please provide any feedback as you see fit.

It gave me 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsDZI.png) result.